# Two checkboxes in MVC, but only want to allow one at a time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my model I have two bool properties, Approved and Rejected. I would like them either as radio buttons or check boxes on the MVC view, but only want one to be selected at a time.

Currently my view looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Approved, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Approved, new { onclick="SingleCheckbox(this)" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Approved, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rejected, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rejected, new { onclick="SingleCheckbox(this)" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rejected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript looks like this:

```
SingleCheckbox = function(rb) {
    debugger;
    var id = rb.id, uncheck;
    if (id == 'Approved') {
        uncheck = document.getElementById('Rejected');
    } else {
        uncheck = document.getElementById('Approved');
    }
};
```

But when I inspect the element, it doesn't even have the onclick event.

I've updated my code to reflect your recommendations (see above) and still have the same issue. The issue is that when I inspect the element the check box inputs DO NOT have an onclick event.

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Approved">Approved</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input class="check-box" id="Approved" name="Approved" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Approved" type="hidden" value="false">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Approved" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Rejected">Rejected</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input class="check-box" id="Rejected" name="Rejected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Rejected" type="hidden" value="false">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Rejected" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a side note from your original question but I think you can solve your problem and have a better UX experience if you instead use radio buttons. Checkboxes imply that more than one selection is allowed (i.e. they usually include a phrase such as _"Check all that apply"_). Radio buttons on the other hand are specifically designed for ***one and only one*** selection at a time...

Comment: Can you show an example of radio buttons that use 2 separate bools?

Comment: If those 2 values are mutually exclusive, then you have a design problem. You should have a singe property (say) `Status` (either a `string` or an `enum`) and use radio buttons and avoid the unnecessary scripts (and the need to repeat the validation again on the server)

Answer (score 1):

Call `SingleCheckbox(this)` instead of `SingleCheckbox.call(this)` in `onclick` of chackbox like following.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Approved, new { onclick = "SingleCheckbox(this)" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Rejected, new { onclick = "SingleCheckbox(this)" })
```

And `SingleCheckbox` should be like following.

```
var SingleCheckbox = function (rb) {
    var id = rb.id, uncheck;
    if (id == 'Approved') {
        uncheck = document.getElementById('Rejected');
    } else {
        uncheck = document.getElementById('Approved');
    }

    uncheck.checked = false;
}
```

**Update:** In asp.net mvc4 and it's earlier version `@Html.EditorFor` has no parameter for `htmlAtrributes`. You can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` instead.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It did not. My initial problem still remains. When the page is rendered, it does not include the onclick. I get this: `<div class="checkbox">
<input class="check-box" id="Approved" name="Approved" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Approved" type="hidden" value="false"></div>`

Comment: @Azim don't you think it should be like this: new{@onclick = '"SingleCheckbox(this)"'}

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be with the `@Html.EditorFor` helper. I changed my code and now it's working.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Approved, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Approved, new { onclick = "SingleCheckbox(this)" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Approved, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rejected, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Rejected, new { onclick = "SingleCheckbox(this)" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rejected, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

I just have to update the javascript to be more generic, I may want to use this in other areas of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hopefully it will render the required markup having onclick in it

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Approved, new { @onclick = '"SingleCheckbox.call(this)"' })
```